# __slots__ in subclass of `object`

Tags: python

Maybe I'm a little bit nitpicky, but there is the following statement in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), about the definition of `__slots__`:

> When inheriting from a class without `__slots__`, the `__dict__` attribute
>   of that class will always be accessible, so a `__slots__` definition in
>   the subclass is meaningless.

However, `object` does not have a `__slots__` and surely have a `__dict__`. How could a definition of `__slots__` in a subclass of `object` have any effect?

Comment: As Alex Martelli puts it in the dupe (emphasis mine) - *"Classes with dict-less instances are those which define `__slots__`, **plus most built-in types**"* - `object` instances don't have a dict, `object().__dict__` is an `AttributeError`.

Comment: `object` is a builtin type that isn't implemented directly in python, so I wouldn't expect to see `__slots__` anywhere. However it certainly has something equivalent going on. It has no `__dict__` attribute either and you can't assign new attributes to it (try `object().x = 3` in a console) much like classes with slots.

Comment: So the point is the _instances_ of any superclass are dict-less, rather than the superclasses _themselves_ being dict-less? But it seems the documentation only mentioned "the `__dict__` attribute of _that class_". Can you point me to any reference on this matter?